# Why did SNMP4J return different result with Net-SNMP?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmp4j

I find that with Net-SNMP, I can get the normal ifPhysAddress result .But when I use SNMP4J,I get some wrong result.How to fix it ?
The Net-SNMP result:
[image]
The snmp4j result:
[image]

Comment: It is just a different formatting of the result value - hex string vs. binary.

Comment: @GambitSupport,Can you show me a method that hexString2binaryString? I have try,but it throw a exception.

Comment: public static String hexString2binaryString(String hexString) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(hexString)) {
            return null;
        }
        String binaryString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < hexString.length(); i++) { 
            String hex = hexString.substring(i, i + 1); 
            String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(hex, 16)); 
            String tmp = "0000" + binary; 
            binaryString += tmp.substring(tmp.length() - 4);
        }
        return binaryString;
    }

Answer (score 0):

That's absolutely normal.

NET-SNMP ships with a set of default MIB documents, so when it makes SNMP operations derived data types (like `PhysAddress` for `ifPhysAddress`) can be interpreted more accurately according to the MIB documents.

However, when you consume the raw SNMP4J library, MIB documents are not involved and the only way is to print out `ifPhysAddress` as the base type of `OCTET STRING` which is effectively raw bytes and garble characters.

If you like to achieve the same output like NET-SNMP, you can buy [SNMP4J's MIB library](https://agentpp.com/api/java/snmp4jsmipro.html) or search for other alternative ways.

Comment: In fact ,SNMP4J can return some correct result and some uncorrect result in one seach process.Can you show me some alternative ways?